# Ford Focus 2012 Continuous Wiper Issue

Tags: ford, focus, windshield-wipers, zetec

I run a 2012 Ford Focus Zetec which has been having an issue, I think, when the wipers are set to continuous mode.

Occasionally, the wipers will switch to intermittent mode when in continuous mode. The wiper speed selector has no bearing on how often the wipers run when this happens. I didn't think this car had a windscreen sensor so I'm confused how it would do this.

Has anyone else had this issue, or is my car smarter than I thought?

Comment: My VW wipers switch to slow intermittent automatically when I'm stopped at a light.  And some cars do have wipers that speed up with the speed of the vehicle.  Does any of that sound familiar?

Comment: Hi - no, there's no real pattern to when/if it happens. Maybe it has some kind of primitive rain sensor, but I didn't think the Zetec model had that.

Comment: If you look at the windshield, like right behind the rear view mirror, a rain sensor will be obvious if present.  I was thinking along the lines of having a speed sensitive wiper that might have something wrong with the speed signal.

Comment: There's two "units" behind the mirror, but these look like the feed to the windscreen heater. I think I'll mention it on my next service.

Comment: I found a bunch of common issue threads related to what you describe.  The solution was to change wiper relay.  The problem is that are not removable and a part of the fuse board which means a total replacement of that.  Additionally, you apparently need to reprogram the key fob i this is done.  Mind you, I don't know any of this.  It's what I researched on the Internet.  Hope this is a good breadcrumb.